# Any way to filter or mask karate Authorization header in request / response?

Tags: security, basic-authentication, production-environment, karate

I'm writing some prod/smoke tests using karate and I want to avoid logging the credentials. It would be nice to see the request/response without the Authorization header or with the credentials masked.

I've set the com.intuit.karate logging level to WARN. This hides the entire request/response from logs/reports.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is planned in the roadmap: https://github.com/intuit/karate/projects/3#card-22529225

This is non-trivial and may need some community contribution. In the meantime, you could experiment with running a brute-force regex replace on the *.log and *.json files during / after test-suite runs.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you!